# ExpandableListView get group text

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView, I've made custom adapter and ExpandListGroup class which holds Name and Subitems.

Every Subitem also has an ImageButton and when clicked I would like to get the Group Name. I tried using OnGroupExpandListener but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways:

1. The way the data structure is set for an Expandable List view, you should be able to get the group name by looking at the group ID/position.
2. You could set the group name as tags to child views. So, you could do a getTag(), and get the group name.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html

Comment: How would I get GroupID on ImageButton click? Also, ImageButtons are defined in xml therefore I can't set tag :/

Comment: Ok, I managed to set tag for ImageButton using getGroupView custom adapter function :)